# Why can't I wrap \rowcolor in \only? (Beamer)

Tags: beamer, tables, color

See the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Boo}
\begin{table}
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{rcc}
\only<1>{\rowcolor{green}}Hey & 32.0 & 26.7\\
\only<2>{\rowcolor{green}}Hey & 28.5 & 24.5\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{My caption}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This gives the error `! Misplaced \noalign`

Why does this not work and how can I get the desired result of highlighted rows on different overlays?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `\rowcolor` command uses `\noalign` to add some code which should not be aligned like the usual table content. The same macro is used to draw the horizontal table lines. It can only be used between rows, i.e. direct after `\\`. The `\only` already starts the first cell of the row and therefore `\noalign` can't work.

#### Here three different solutions which are getting more and more generic:

One way to make this work is to place the `\rowcolor` code into a custom macro which is empty otherwise. This is OK because TeX expands macros at the begin of cells to look for included `\noalign`s.

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Boo}
\begin{table}
\centering
\small
\def\firstrowcolor{}
\def\secondrowcolor{}
\only<1>{\def\firstrowcolor{\rowcolor{green}}}
\only<2>{\def\secondrowcolor{\rowcolor{green}}}
\begin{tabular}{rcc}
\firstrowcolor Hey & 32.0 & 26.7\\
\secondrowcolor Hey & 28.5 & 24.5\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{My caption}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

An alternative would be to change `\rowcolor` to accept the `beamer` overlay specifications directly:

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}

% Redefine `\rowcolor` to allow a beamer overlay specifier
% New syntax: \rewcolor<overlay>[color model]{color}[left overhang][right overhang]
\makeatletter
% Open `\noalign` and check for overlay specification:
\def\rowcolor{\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\bmr@rowcolor}
\newcommand<>{\bmr@rowcolor}{%
    \alt#1%
        {\global\let\CT@do@color\CT@@do@color\@ifnextchar[\CT@rowa\CT@rowb}% Rest of original `\rowcolor`
        {\ifnum0=`{\fi}\@gooble@rowcolor}% End `\noalign` and gobble all arguments of `\rowcolor`.
}
% Gobble all normal arguments of `\rowcolor`:
\newcommand{\@gooble@rowcolor}[2][]{\@gooble@rowcolor@}
\newcommand{\@gooble@rowcolor@}[1][]{\@gooble@rowcolor@@}
\newcommand{\@gooble@rowcolor@@}[1][]{\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}%
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \rowcolor<1>{green} A & B \\
    \rowcolor<2>{green} D & C \\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \rowcolor<1>{green}[0pt][1pt] A & B \\
    \rowcolor<2>{green}[0pt][1pt] D & C \\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \rowcolor<1>[named]{green}[0pt][1pt] A & B \\
    \rowcolor<2>[named]{green}[0pt][1pt] D & C \\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

I finally had the idea to provide some overlay aware macros which take row-specific macros like `\hline` or `\rowcolor` as arguments. This way you 
can have different row colors on different slides. There is `\rowonly`, `\rowalt` and `\rowtemporal` which work like `\only`, `\alt` and `\temporal`. See the examples at the end.

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rowonly}{%
    \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
    \@rowonly
}
\newcommand<>{\@rowonly}[1]{%
    \only#2%
        {\ifnum0=`{\fi}#1{\ifnum0=`}\fi}%
    \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
    \ignorespaces
}

\newcommand{\rowalt}{%
    \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
    \@rowalt
}
\newcommand<>{\@rowalt}[2]{%
    \alt#3%
        {\ifnum0=`{\fi}#1{\ifnum0=`}\fi}%
        {\ifnum0=`{\fi}#2{\ifnum0=`}\fi}%
    \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
    \ignorespaces
}

\newcommand{\rowtemporal}{%
    \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
    \@rowtemporal
}
\newcommand<>{\@rowtemporal}[3]{%
    \temporal#4%
        {\ifnum0=`{\fi}#1{\ifnum0=`}\fi}%
        {\ifnum0=`{\fi}#2{\ifnum0=`}\fi}%
        {\ifnum0=`{\fi}#3{\ifnum0=`}\fi}%
    \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
    \ignorespaces
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1-3>{Test}%
\begin{tabular}{ll}
   \rowcolor{blue} A & B \\
   \rowonly<1>{\hline} A & B \\
   \rowonly<1>{\rowcolor{yellow}} A & B \\
   \rowalt<3>{\rowcolor{green}}{\rowcolor{red}} C & D \\
   \rowtemporal<2>{\rowcolor{green}}{\rowcolor{yellow}}{\rowcolor{red}} E & F \\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So it *is* in fact a misplaced `\noalign`!  Who said error messages were worthless?

Comment: This answer's first paragraph needs to be put somewhere prominent. It actually can prevent a lot of frustration. Maybe on the first page of the `xcolor` and `colortbl` documentations. Obviously the beamer documentation could use it as well.

Answer (score 5):

Martin Scharrer explained the problem very well, but I think there is a better (simpler) solution to work around. Try

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Boo}
\begin{table}
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{rcc}
\rowcolor{green}}Hey & 32.0 & 26.7\only<1>{\\}
\only<2>{\\\rowcolor{green}}Hey & 28.5 & 24.5\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{My caption}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually compile for me. Additionally, it would be helpful to explain what your solution actually does.

Comment: You have an extra `}` for `\rowcolor`.

Comment: Works for me (after fixing the extra `}`). It's like magic!

Comment: Seems that this solution is based on "moving" the newline mark ``\\`` just before the `\rowcolor`, which prevents LaTeX from inserting any code between the ``\\`` and the `\rowcolor`.

Comment: Worked really well, but I had problems in rows that are right after the `\hline`.

Answer (score 1):

for simple tables you can use `\only` for the whole table:

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Boo}

\only<1>{%
  \begin{tabular}{rcc}
  \rowcolor{green}Hey & 32.0 & 26.7\\
                  Hey & 28.5 & 24.5\\
  \end{tabular}}
\only<2>{%
  \begin{tabular}{rcc}
                  Hey & 32.0 & 26.7\\
  \rowcolor{green}Hey & 28.5 & 24.5\\
  \end{tabular}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is not important for the compilation. You can try as first line

```
\batchmode
```

in your document, then the pdf should be created as usual.