# Could I use \columncolor with \only? (Beamer)

Tags: tables, beamer, color, columns

In [Why can't I wrap \rowcolor in \only? (Beamer)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18427/2015), there are solutions to how to use `\rowcolor` with `\only` in Beamer. Is there a way to use `\columncolor` in a similar way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\columncolor` macro seems to be very special handled<sup>1</sup> and can't be patched to support `beamer` overlays. I would do it be using custom column types which are defined differently depending on the overlay:

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<1-3>

\alt<2>
{\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{blue}}c}}
{\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{yellow}}c}}

\temporal<2>
{\newcolumntype{b}{c}}
{\newcolumntype{b}{>{\columncolor{green}}c}}
{\newcolumntype{b}{>{\columncolor{red}}c}}

\begin{tabular}{ab}
   A &  B \\
   A &  B \\
   A &  B \\
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact `\columncolor` is never defined at all! Another internal tabular macro simply scans the tabular preamble for it and extracts the argument of it!

Comment: Works perfectly! Although I do not fully understand the syntax...:)

Comment: @Lee: See the `array` package manual. `>{code}` adds the `code` before (`>`) every cell. There is also `<{code}` which adds it afterwards and must be used after the column character.