# Cell coloring (highlighting) with in-out effects in a table in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, highlighting, pause, cellcolor

I need cell coloring (or highlight effect) in a cell of a table in [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) after a click (I mean, I am planning to talk about something in that frame and I will emphasize just a number in a cell at the end of my talk), and I tried many commands such as `\onslide<>`, `\only<>`, `\visible<>`, and new commands use `\colorbox` but any of them worked. Lastly, I came across some [`\rowcolor<>{colorname}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68371/how-to-highlight-table-rows-by-colors-in-beamer) codes and I tried to arrange those codes (without know newcommand structure completely) for cell coloring with in-out effects but there is something wrong so I got an error like that

Misplaced `\noalign`.

What is the problem with it?

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{gray!10}

\makeatletter
\def\rowcolor{\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\bmr@rowcolor}
\newcommand<>{\bmr@rowcolor}{%
    \alt#1%
        {\global\let\CT@do@color\CT@@do@color\@ifnextchar[\CT@rowa\CT@rowb}% 
        {\ifnum0=`{\fi}\@gooble@rowcolor}% 
}

\newcommand{\@gooble@rowcolor}[2][]{\@gooble@rowcolor@}
\newcommand{\@gooble@rowcolor@}[1][]{\@gooble@rowcolor@@}
\newcommand{\@gooble@rowcolor@@}[1][]{\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\cellcolor{\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\bmr@cellcolor}
\newcommand<>{\bmr@cellcolor}{%
    \alt#1%
        {\global\let\CT@do@color\CT@@do@color\@ifnextchar[\CT@rowa\CT@rowb}% 
        {\ifnum0=`{\fi}\@gooble@cellcolor}% 
}

\newcommand{\@gooble@cellcolor}[2][]{\@gooble@cellcolor@}
\newcommand{\@gooble@cellcolor@}[1][]{\@gooble@cellcolor@@}
\newcommand{\@gooble@cellcolor@@}[1][]{\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{The MWE}%

\only<2>{\rowcolors{1}{blue!30}{blue!10}}
\only<1,3>{\rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{gray!10}}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    A & B \\
    A & B \\
    A & B \\
    \rowcolor<4>{green} C & D \\
    \rowcolor<4,5>{yellow} E & F \\
    \rowcolor<4-6>{green} G & H \\
    \rowcolor<6>{red} Y & S \\
    A & B \
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\par    
\visible<1>{Testing default row colouring ... \\}
\visible<2,3>{Testing change of default colors ...\\}
\visible<4-6>{Testing in-out of custom colors ...\\ (caution: The order of defaults colors can change)\\}

\vfill
\scriptsize{
 Based of answer of Martin Scharrer
 \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18427/why-cant-i-wrap-rowcolor-in-only-beamer}}

\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}{Cell Coloring with In-out Effects}
   \begin{center}
   \begin{tabular}{cc}
    A & B \\
    C & \cellcolor<3>{green} C \\
    D & E \\
    F & G \
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: see the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378511/36296

Answer (score 8):

Delete the `\noalign` command from the definition of `\cellcolor`:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{gray!10}

\makeatletter
\def\rowcolor{\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\bmr@rowcolor}
\newcommand<>{\bmr@rowcolor}{%
    \alt#1%
        {\global\let\CT@do@color\CT@@do@color\@ifnextchar[\CT@rowa\CT@rowb}% 
        {\ifnum0=`{\fi}\@gooble@rowcolor}% 
}

\newcommand{\@gooble@rowcolor}[2][]{\@gooble@rowcolor@}
\newcommand{\@gooble@rowcolor@}[1][]{\@gooble@rowcolor@@}
\newcommand{\@gooble@rowcolor@@}[1][]{\ignorespaces}
\makeatother



\makeatletter
\def\cellcolor{{\ifnum0=`}\fi\bmr@cellcolor}
\newcommand<>{\bmr@cellcolor}{%
    \alt#1%
        {\global\let\CT@do@color\CT@@do@color\@ifnextchar[\CT@rowa\CT@rowb}% 
        {\ifnum0=`{\fi}\@gooble@cellcolor}% 
}

\newcommand{\@gooble@cellcolor}[2][]{\@gooble@cellcolor@}
\newcommand{\@gooble@cellcolor@}[1][]{\@gooble@cellcolor@@}
\newcommand{\@gooble@cellcolor@@}[1][]{\ignorespaces}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{The MWE}%

\only<2>{\rowcolors{1}{blue!30}{blue!10}}
\only<1,3>{\rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{gray!10}}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    A & B \\
    A & B \\
    A & B \\
    \rowcolor<4>{green} C & D \\
    \rowcolor<4,5>{yellow} E & F \\
    \rowcolor<4-6>{green} G & H \\
    \rowcolor<6>{red} Y & S \\
    A & B \\

\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\par    
\visible<1>{Testing default row colouring ... \\}
\visible<2,3>{Testing change of default colors ...\\}
\visible<4-6>{Testing in-out of custom colors ...\\ (caution: The order of defaults colors can change)\\}

\vfill
\scriptsize{
 Based of answer of Martin Scharrer
 \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18427/why-cant-i-wrap-rowcolor-in-only-beamer}}

\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}{Cell Coloring with In-out Effects}
   \begin{center}
   \begin{tabular}{cc}
    A & B \\
    C & \cellcolor<3>{green} C \\
    D & E \\
    F & G \\

    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working in my case. If I move \cellcolor<3>{green} in the last table to the first cell in the row, it will highlight the whole row, not just the cell. Or am I missing something?