# Gradually color table cells in Latex beamer

Tags: tables, beamer

I have a beamer slide whose code looks similar to the one below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{My title}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would now like to gradually highlight certain cells of my table in a certain color (e.g. green).

For example, the cell with value 1 would be highlighted in green first. After that, the cell with value 2 would be highlighted, etc...

How would I go about that? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and easy way: use `\alert`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=green!80!black}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{My title}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\alert<+>{1} & \alert<+>{2} & \alert<+>{3} \\
\alert<+>{4} & \alert<+>{5} & \alert<+>{6} \\
\alert<+>{7} & \alert<+>{8} & \alert<+>{9}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

If you don't want to change the font colour but the background of the cell, you could use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378511/36296

Answer (score 2):

And not only highlight the cell, you can also treat distinctively the preceding and following cells.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\geometry{paperheight=1.5in,paperwidth=1.5in}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamercovered{%dynamic,
still covered={\opaqueness<1>{30}\opaqueness<2>{20}\opaqueness<3->{10}},
again covered={\opaqueness<1->{70}}}
\def\x#1{\uncover<#1>{\structure<#1->{\alert<#1>{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\x1 & \x2 & \x3 \\
\x4 & \x5 & \x6 \\
\x7 & \x8 & \x9
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```