# How Do I Highlight Table Rows in beamer, Piecewise?

Tags: tables, beamer, highlighting

I would like to know how to highlight rows within a table in [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer), piecewise, so that when I present the piece, I can originally have no rows highlighted, and then the first, and then both the first and the second, etc.

I have the following table, with the first two rows highlighted:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}    
\begin{tabular}{lcc|ccc}
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Effect of Mandate on Fertility by Age: Employed Individuals} \\ \hline \hline
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\
 & Has Child & Has Child LT 5 & Has Child LT 5 & Has Child LT 5 & Has Child LT 5 \\
VARIABLES & All & All & No HS Degree & HS or College & Masters or More \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
\rowcolor{LRed} Married Women 18-20*& -0.11 & -0.08* & -0.21*** & -0.00 & 0.00 \\
\rowcolor{LRed} After*Treatment State & [0.071] & [0.045] & [0.069] & [0.055] & [0.000]     \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
\rowcolor{LRed} Married Women 20-25*& -0.07*** & -0.07*** & -0.04 & -0.08*** & -0.38* \\
\rowcolor{LRed} After*Treatment State & [0.023] & [0.015] & [0.036] & [0.016] & [0.215] \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
Married Women 25-30*& -0.00 & 0.03** & 0.19*** & 0.01 & 0.11* \\
After*Treatment State & [0.019] & [0.012] & [0.032] & [0.014] & [0.058] \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
Married Women 30-35*& 0.01 & -0.01 & -0.09*** & -0.01 & 0.12** \\
After*Treatment State & [0.020] & [0.012] & [0.029] & [0.014] & [0.051] \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
Married Women 35-40*& -0.01 & -0.02** & -0.07*** & -0.03* & 0.10* \\
After*Treatment State & [0.019] & [0.012] & [0.026] & [0.014] & [0.053] \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
Observations & 152,366 & 152,366 & 34,081 & 110,324 & 7,961 \\
R-squared & 0.38 & 0.24 & 0.28 & 0.24 & 0.17 \\
 Mean of Dependant Variable & 0.48 & 0.09 & 0.07 & 0.10 & 0.08 \\ \hline \hline
\multicolumn{6}{c}{ Standard errors in brackets} \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Is this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68371/how-to-highlight-table-rows-by-colors-in-beamer helpful?

Answer (score 13):

The solution linked in the comments is the most appropriate, but one might also use the `hf-tikz` package (with a bit of abstraction as it's not the main purpose of the package).

A possible implementation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}

\tikzset{hl/.style={
    set fill color=red!80!black!40,
    set border color=red!80!black,
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{lcc|ccc}
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Effect of Mandate on Fertility by Age: Employed Individuals} \\ \hline \hline
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\
 & Has Child & Has Child LT 5 & Has Child LT 5 & Has Child LT 5 & Has Child LT 5 \\
VARIABLES & All & All & No HS Degree & HS or College & Masters or More \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
\tikzmarkin<2->[hl]{a} Married Women 18-20*& -0.11 & -0.08* & -0.21*** & -0.00 & 0.00 \\
 After*Treatment State & [0.071] & [0.045] & [0.069] & [0.055] & [0.000] \tikzmarkend{a}    \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
\tikzmarkin<3->[hl]{b} Married Women 20-25*& -0.07*** & -0.07*** & -0.04 & -0.08*** & -0.38* \\
 After*Treatment State & [0.023] & [0.015] & [0.036] & [0.016] & [0.215] \tikzmarkend{b} \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
Married Women 25-30*& -0.00 & 0.03** & 0.19*** & 0.01 & 0.11* \\
After*Treatment State & [0.019] & [0.012] & [0.032] & [0.014] & [0.058] \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
Married Women 30-35*& 0.01 & -0.01 & -0.09*** & -0.01 & 0.12** \\
After*Treatment State & [0.020] & [0.012] & [0.029] & [0.014] & [0.051] \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
Married Women 35-40*& -0.01 & -0.02** & -0.07*** & -0.03* & 0.10* \\
After*Treatment State & [0.019] & [0.012] & [0.026] & [0.014] & [0.053] \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
Observations & 152,366 & 152,366 & 34,081 & 110,324 & 7,961 \\
R-squared & 0.38 & 0.24 & 0.28 & 0.24 & 0.17 \\
 Mean of Dependant Variable & 0.48 & 0.09 & 0.07 & 0.10 & 0.08 \\ \hline \hline
\multicolumn{6}{c}{ Standard errors in brackets} \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

A remark: the `\resizebox` has been adopted as the table does not fit the frame. It comes from `graphicx`, a package automatically loaded by Beamer, so no need of load it explicitly.

Comment: I really like the quality of the result, but that extra space inserted at the beginning of the marked lines is tickling my OCD. Is that caused by beamer uncovering or hf-tikz?

Comment: Okay, answered my own question. It is caused by tikzmarkin, and can be fixed by appending the tikzmarkin command with `\unskip`. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280198/beamer-annotated-tables/283304

Comment: The result is brilliant. How can I remove the highlight of a row before highlighting another one ?

Comment: @Irazza: just remove the `-`, i.e., say `\tikzmarkin<2>`.

Answer (score 3):

In an effort to complete this question, I borrowed the answer of [fran](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68380/36296) as this seems to be a relative simple solution to the present problem

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{gray!10}

\makeatletter
\def\rowcolor{\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\bmr@rowcolor}
\newcommand<>{\bmr@rowcolor}{%
    \alt#1%
        {\global\let\CT@do@color\CT@@do@color\@ifnextchar[\CT@rowa\CT@rowb}% 
        {\ifnum0=`{\fi}\@gooble@rowcolor}% 
}

\newcommand{\@gooble@rowcolor}[2][]{\@gooble@rowcolor@}
\newcommand{\@gooble@rowcolor@}[1][]{\@gooble@rowcolor@@}
\newcommand{\@gooble@rowcolor@@}[1][]{\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{The MWE}%

\only<2>{\rowcolors{1}{blue!30}{blue!10}}
\only<1,3>{\rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{gray!10}}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    A & B \\
    A & B \\
    A & B \\
    \rowcolor<4>{green} A & B \\
    \rowcolor<4,5>{yellow}A & B \\
    \rowcolor<4-6>{green}A & B \\
    \rowcolor<6>{red} A & B \\
    A & B \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\par    
\visible<1>{Testing default row colouring ... }

\visible<2,3>{Testing change of default colors ...}

\visible<4-6>{Testing in-out of custom colors ...

(caution: The order of defaults colors can change)}

\vfill
\scriptsize{
Based of answer of Martin Scharrer
 \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18427/why-cant-i-wrap-rowcolor-in-only-beamer}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```