# Annotate the table column highlighted by Tikzmark in Beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, color, tikzmark

I would like to highlight columns in my table using Tikzmark in Beamer. Here bellow is an example which does the same thing but for the table rows. I would like to know if is it possible to do the same thing whith columns:

[Annotate the table row highlighted by Tikzmark in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270221/annotate-the-table-row-highlighted-by-tikzmark-in-beamer/273708#273708)

Thank you in advance.

Best,
T.

Comment: Did you try it? Place `\tikzmarkin` before first column and row element and `\tikzmarkend` after last column and row element.

Comment: Thank you Ignasi for your answer. 

I tried it, but it does not work. When I change \tikzmarkin and \tikzmarkend, the code highlights all cells between the first and the last selected elements (by rows). what I want is to highlight just a column. Thanks once again. Best, T.

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS} 
\usecolortheme{beaver}

% The usual suspects
\usepackage{booktabs} % Tables
% The table highlighting for hypothesis discussion.
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% To set the hypothesis highlighting boxes red.
\tikzset{hl/.style={
    set fill color=red!80!black!40,
    set border color=red!80!black,
  },
}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table highlighted by columns}

\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\toprule
A & B & C \\
\midrule

1 &\tikzmarkin<1>{col}2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8\tikzmarkend{col} & 9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}% 
\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Tarik Instead of posting a “Thank you”, you should consider to thank Ignasi by accepting the answer (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).