# Annotate row and column highlighted in one table with different color by Tikzmark in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, color, annotations

I found example for row only here: [Annotate the table row highlighted by Tikzmark in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270221/annotate-the-table-row-highlighted-by-tikzmark-in-beamer)

Also found example for column only here: [Annotate the table column highlighted by Tikzmark in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273790/annotate-the-table-column-highlighted-by-tikzmark-in-beamer)

but never found an example to highlight row and column simultaneously in one table with different color.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

As in [Annotate the table column highlighted by Tikzmark in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273790/annotate-the-table-column-highlighted-by-tikzmark-in-beamer), but with a new marker for the row.

In this case it's better not to draw borders.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS} 
\usecolortheme{beaver}

% The usual suspects
\usepackage{booktabs} % Tables
% The table highlighting for hypothesis discussion.
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\hfsetbordercolor{none}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table highlighted by columns}

\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\toprule
A & B & C \\
\midrule

1 &\tikzmarkin<2>{col}2 & 3 \\
\tikzmarkin<2>{row}4 & 5 & 6\tikzmarkend{row} \\
7 & 8\tikzmarkend{col} & 9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}% 
\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]