# How do I highlight parts of a table?

Tags: tables, beamer, highlighting

I would like to do something similar to [How Do I Highlight Table Rows in beamer, Piecewise?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132804/how-do-i-highlight-table-rows-in-beamer-piecewise)

But instead of only highlighting complete rows, I want to highlight arbitrary subsets of the table.

I added the code of the original question as well as the output. Which changes would have to be done to e.g. highlight the first 2 columns of the first 2 data rows in a contiguous block?

Additionally the code leads to the highlighted rows being indented, which I would like to avoid.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}

\tikzset{hl/.style={
    set fill color=red!80!black!40,
    set border color=red!80!black,
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{lcc|ccc}
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Effect of Mandate on Fertility by Age: Employed Individuals} \\ \hline \hline
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\
 & Has Child & Has Child LT 5 & Has Child LT 5 & Has Child LT 5 & Has Child LT 5 \\
VARIABLES & All & All & No HS Degree & HS or College & Masters or More \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
\tikzmarkin<2->[hl]{a} Married Women 18-20*& -0.11 & -0.08* & -0.21*** & -0.00 & 0.00 \\
 After*Treatment State & [0.071] & [0.045] & [0.069] & [0.055] & [0.000] \tikzmarkend{a}    \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
\tikzmarkin<3->[hl]{b} Married Women 20-25*& -0.07*** & -0.07*** & -0.04 & -0.08*** & -0.38* \\
 After*Treatment State & [0.023] & [0.015] & [0.036] & [0.016] & [0.215] \tikzmarkend{b} \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
Married Women 25-30*& -0.00 & 0.03** & 0.19*** & 0.01 & 0.11* \\
After*Treatment State & [0.019] & [0.012] & [0.032] & [0.014] & [0.058] \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
Married Women 30-35*& 0.01 & -0.01 & -0.09*** & -0.01 & 0.12** \\
After*Treatment State & [0.020] & [0.012] & [0.029] & [0.014] & [0.051] \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
Married Women 35-40*& -0.01 & -0.02** & -0.07*** & -0.03* & 0.10* \\
After*Treatment State & [0.019] & [0.012] & [0.026] & [0.014] & [0.053] \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
Observations & 152,366 & 152,366 & 34,081 & 110,324 & 7,961 \\
R-squared & 0.38 & 0.24 & 0.28 & 0.24 & 0.17 \\
 Mean of Dependant Variable & 0.48 & 0.09 & 0.07 & 0.10 & 0.08 \\ \hline \hline
\multicolumn{6}{c}{ Standard errors in brackets} \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just place `\tikzmarkin` and corresponding `tikzmarkend` at the opposite corners of the desired area. This means, `tikzmarkin` before the top left element and `tikzmarkend` after the bottom right one.

Comment: Oh, I falsely expected it to mark the row then.
But somehow it still draws the border a little bit too high and indent the upper left cell.

Comment: Don't leave any space between command and data.

Comment: I tried this earlier, but it unfortunately doesn't help

Comment: I can post a separate question for this with more information and if you post your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: You can apply [`cfr's` patch](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283304/1952) to `hf-tikz`

Comment: And please also consider her comment http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280198/beamer-annotated-tables/283304#comment683233_283304

Comment: With Ti*k*Z's `\matrix` it will mark the positions for you automatically.