# Rectangles around cells in table - fit not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, beamer, multirow

I'm trying to fit a rectangle around multiple cells, using the solutions suggested in other posts.

However, for some reason, my multiple cell rectangle ends up outside the table and I see no reason why.

Here's a MWE: I would like the rounded square to fit around 88 and 11-13 in Ireland row.

Thank you very much.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\reserveinserts{28}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}

\newcounter{nodemarkers}
\newcommand\circletext[1]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
    \node (marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-a) at (0,1.5ex) {};%
    #1%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]
    \node (marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-b) at (0,0){};%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=3pt]
    \node[draw, red, ultra thick, rounded corners,fit=(marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-a.center) (marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-b.center)] {};%
    \stepcounter{nodemarkers}%
}

\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][]{%
    \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}}%
    \ifnum \@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
    \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
    \list
    {\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}
    {\def\makelabel##1{%
            {%
                \hss\llap{{%
                        \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                        \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
            }%
        }%
    }
    \fi%
    \beamer@cramped%
    \justifying

    \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}
\makeatother
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography item}{fg=black}  %new code


\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{shadow theme}{%
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fil,rightskip=.3cm]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\hfill\insertshortauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}%

        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hfill%
            \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    } 

    % Standard packages

    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{times}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


    % Setup TikZ

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \tikzstyle{block}=[draw opacity=0.7,line width=1.4cm]


    % Author, Title, etc.








    % The main document

    \begin{document}
        \newcounter{nodecount}
        % Command for making a new node and naming it according to the nodecount     counter
        \newcommand\tabnode[1]{\addtocounter{nodecount}{1} \tikz \node  (\arabic{nodecount}) {#1};}




        \begin{frame}{Identification of the Fiscal Episodes (1970-2013) (cont'd)}

            \begin{table}[!p]

                \scalebox{0.47}{
                    \begin{tabular}{cccccccccccc}
                        \toprule
                        \midrule
                        &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{\textit{FE\textsuperscript{1}}}} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{\textit{FE\textsuperscript{2}}}} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{\textit{FE\textsuperscript{3}}}} &  \\
                        \cmidrule{2-2} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{7-8} \cmidrule{10-11}
                        & \textbf{ Country} & \textbf{} & \textbf{Expansions} & \textbf{Contractions} & \textbf{} & \textbf{Expansions} & \textbf{Contractions} & \textbf{} & \textbf{Expansions} & \textbf{Contractions} &  \\
                        \cmidrule{2-11}
                        & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Ireland}} & \textbf{} & 01-02, & \tabnode{88,}   &       & 95, 01-02, & \circletext{88},   &       & 95, 01-02,  & \circletext{88},   &  \\

                        &       & \textbf{} &  07-10 & \tabnode{11-13} &       & 07-10 & \circletext{11-13} &       & 07-10 & \circletext{11-13} &  \\
                        \cmidrule{2-11}
                        & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Italy}} & \textbf{} &       & 83, 92-94, &       & 81,   & 82-83,  &       & 81,   & 82-83, &  \\
                        &       & \textbf{} &       & 12    &       & 01    & 92-93, 12 &       & 01    & 92-93, 12 &  \\
                        \cmidrule{2-11}
                        & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Netherlands}} & \textbf{} & 02,   & 91,   &       & 01-02,  & 91, 93, &       & 01,   & 91, 93, &  \\

                        &       & \textbf{} & 09-10 & 93    &       & 09-10 & 96    &       & 09    & 96    &  \\
                        \cmidrule{2-11}
                        & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Portugal}} & \textbf{} & 78-80, 94,  & 83-84,  &       & 78-79, 85, 93-94, & 83-84, 86, 88, &       & 78, 85, 93, & 83, 86, 88, &  \\

                        &       & \textbf{} & 09-10 & \circletext{11-13} &       & 05, 09-10 & 92, \circletext{11-13} &       & 05, 09-10 & 92, \circletext{11-13} &  \\
                        \cmidrule{2-11}
                        & \textbf{Spain} & \textbf{} & 08-11 & 13    &       & 08-09 &  13   &       & 08-09 &  13   &  \\
                        \cmidrule{2-11}
                        & \textbf{Sweden} & \textbf{} & 02-03 & 96-99 &       & 02    & 96-97 &       & 02    & 96-97 &  \\
                        \cmidrule{2-11}
                        & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{United Kingdom}} & \textbf{} & 91-93,  & 97-00, &       & 90-93, & 97-98, 00,  &       & 90, 92-93, & 00, 11 &  \\
                        &       & \textbf{} & 01-04, 09 & 11-13 &       & 01-03, 09 & 11-12 &       & 01-03, 09 &       &  \\
                        \cmidrule{2-11}
                        & \textbf{\# Years with episodes} & \textbf{} & 52    & 62    &       & 63    & 61    &       & 51    & 50    &  \\
                        & \textbf{Avg duration (years)} & \textbf{} & 1.86  & 2.48  &       & 1.62  & 1.65  &       & 1.31  & 1.43  &  \\
                        \midrule
                        \bottomrule
                    \end{tabular}%

                }
                \label{tab:addlabel}%

                \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
                % Define the circle paths
                \node[draw=blue,rounded corners = 1ex,fit=(1)(2),inner sep = 0pt] {};



                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{table}%                

            \end{frame}
            \end{document}
```

Comment: Does [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275504/beamer-annotated-tables-using-tikzmark) help you?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately tikzmarking doesn't solve the problem either. The setup for the coordinates that I used seems right, but somehow the rectangle ends up floating outside the table.

Comment: I copied some solutions in other posts and the squares get messed up in my environment, so I guess this must have something to do with the preamble.

Comment: You have to compile at least twice to get the tikzmark draw at the correct location

Comment: Thank you guys, tikzmark is working now. However, fit environment still results in squares outside the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Sidenote: Your example isn't exactly minimal, there is a lot of stuff in it that isn't used at all. Below I've trimmed things down a bit.)

There are a few problems with your code. First, you need `remember picture,overlay` options for both the `\tikz` macro in the definition of `\tabnode`, and the `tikzpicture` environment where the box is drawn. You also needs to place that `tikzpicture` *inside* the `\scalebox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcounter{nodemarkers}
\newcommand\circletext[1]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
    \node (marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-a) at (0,1.5ex) {};%
    #1%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]
    \node (marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-b) at (0,0){};%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=3pt]
    \node[draw, red, ultra thick, rounded corners,fit=(marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-a.center) (marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-b.center)] {};%
    \stepcounter{nodemarkers}%
}

\newcounter{nodecount}
% Command for making a new node and naming it according to the nodecount     counter
\newcommand\tabnode[1]{\stepcounter{nodecount} \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node  (n\arabic{nodecount}) {#1};}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\scalebox{0.47}{
\begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}
\toprule
               & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{\textit{FE\textsuperscript{1}}}} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{\textit{FE\textsuperscript{2}}}} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{\textit{FE\textsuperscript{3}}}}   \\
                        \cmidrule{1-1} \cmidrule{3-4} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{9-10}
                         \textbf{ Country} &  & \textbf{Expansions} & \textbf{Contractions} &  & \textbf{Expansions} & \textbf{Contractions} &  & \textbf{Expansions} & \textbf{Contractions}   \\
                        \midrule
                         \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Ireland}} &  & 01-02, & \tabnode{88,}   &       & 95, 01-02, & \circletext{88},   &       & 95, 01-02,  & \circletext{88},     \\

                               &  &  07-10 & \tabnode{11-13} &       & 07-10 & \circletext{11-13} &       & 07-10 & \circletext{11-13}   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture] 
% Define the circle paths
\node[draw=blue,rounded corners = 1ex,fit=(n1)(n2),inner sep = 0pt] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

}  % <-- this is the end of the scalebox

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```